# do while loop not working well php

Tags: php, if-statement, do-while

I am trying to push values after they are being calculated to different arrays
as you can see the `min($arrival)` being unset after it enters the while loop everything works fine for the first 3 arrivals `("1","1","1")` but when it hits `("4")` it does not go to the else statement since the (`$minCC` is not > 1) anymore.
I am not sure if there is something wrong with the if statement or the while loop I need help figuring out what's wrong.

```
$alpha = ["A","B","C","D"];
$arrival = ["1","1","1","4"];
$cpu = ["10","2","2","4"];
$final = array(); //start + finish
$inCC = array(); //final cc of inline related to falp
$outCC = array(); //final cc of inline2
$falp = array(); // final a
$start = 0;

$tempc = array(); // => temp for leftc
$tempa = array(); // => temp for lefta

$leftc = array(); // =>merge inCC & outCC
$lefta = array(); // =>merge falp

$hashed = mysql_query("SELECT Alpha FROM fcfs", $connection);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($hashed)){
    $hash[] = $row['Alpha'];
}
/////test
do{
$min = min($arrival);
$findmin = mysql_query("SELECT Alpha,CPU FROM fcfs WHERE Arrival='$min'", $connection);
while($fm = mysql_fetch_assoc($findmin)){
    $ALPHA[] = $fm['Alpha'];
    $minCC[] = $fm['CPU'];
}

/*while(count($minCC) > 0){*/
$keys = array_keys($arrival, $min);
    foreach($keys as $k)
    {
        unset($arrival[$k]);
    }
$min2 = min($arrival);
$diff = $min2 - $min;

    if(count($minCC) > 1){ /// else fasfas el min of mincc
        for($i=0; $i<$diff; $i++){
            if($minCC[$i] == 1){
                array_push($inCC, $minCC[$i]);
                array_push($falp, $ALPHA[$i]);
                unset($minCC[$i]);
                unset($ALPHA[$i]);
                unset($hash[$i]);
            }else{
                array_push($inCC, 1);
                array_push($tempc, ($minCC[$i] - 1));
                array_push($tempa, $ALPHA[$i]);
                unset($minCC[$i]);
                unset($ALPHA[$i]);
                unset($hash[$i]);
            }
        }
    }else{
        array_push($inCC, $minCC[0]);
        array_push($falp, $ALPHA[0]);
        unset($minCC[0]);
        unset($ALPHA[0]);
        unset($hash[0]);
    }
}while(count($hash) > 0); <=== think this goes infinite and page stop working


/* testing each array */
print_r($hash);
echo '<br>';
print_r($tempc);
echo '<br>';
print_r($tempa);
echo '<br>';
print_r($inCC);
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code lines. That will help you to understand the logic, the structure. I myself fail to get it by just looking at your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not reviewed you code very carefully, but what I already see is that seems like you believe that unset($hash[i]) shifts numeric keys remaining elements. So bad news that it DON`T.

Look, if you have such array and make such unset

```
$a = array(10, 20, 30);
unset($a[1]);
```

then

```
echo count($a); // returns 2
echo $a[0]; // 10
echo $a[1]; // undefined
echo $a[2]; // 30
```

so such construction wount work clean array as expected... it even wound end

```
while(count($a))
    unset($a[0]); // delete $a[0] if exists, or delete nothing if array doesnt have $a[0], even if it has $a[1];
```

you code is more complicated, but I guess it based on the same incorrect assumption.

**update**

you could close index gaps with

```
$hash = array_values($hash);
```

after each unset on this array to fix this problem;

Comment: yea i though also about that, the array_values($hash); worked perfectly.
and ("4") entered the right array...
but how does the $arrival[$k] works now? since array_values is not there how does $diff got the value? and continued to execute ("4") as $min = 4, $min2 = ?? <== should be undefined?